# Updating the tooltip content doesnt update because its already initialized?

Tags: javascript, tippyjs

I'm not sure if I've got the title right here, if someone can recommend a better title I'll be happy to change it.

I have website that shows a list of products you can purchase, with a quick "add to wishlist" button. When you hover over the button, the tooltip says "add to wishlist", and when you click the button, the item is added to the wishlist.
The problem is, now that the item is in the wishlist basket, hovering over the button should say "remove from wishlist" but it still says "add to basket".
I'm trying to update this.

My code for displaying the icon is like this, using the `data` attribute.

```
<div class="wishlist-status js-wishlist-icon"  data-tippy-content="@Html.Translate("ADD TO WISHLIST",Context)">
    <partial name="~/Views/Shared/Components/SVG/_IconHeart.cshtml" />
</div>
```

I have a function that controls this functionality. My thinking was that I update this data value, and it will work. So I did this

```
var el = document.querySelector('.js-wishlist-icon');
el.setAttribute('data-tippy-content', 'remove from basket');
```

It does actually work. If I inspect the element, once I click the button, the value of it DOES say "remove from basket" in the markup, its just that the tooltip doesn't say that. It still says **ADD TO WISHLIST** when hovering. I think this is because its set when initialized, but I cant seem to update it.

I think I need an "updateTooltip" function. I think this website was built using Bootstrap, but I dont know if this functionality is Bootstrap or not. I've tried looking at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/ but I'm not convinced anything there will help me.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: The `data-tippy-content` seems to suggest you are using the tippyjs library. Please add the corresponding tag, as obviously pure HTML/JS does not give any special functionality to that attribute.

Comment: Didnt know that was the library. Thanks. updated

Answer (score 1):

I think I encountered a similar problem. I have an input field that I can edit text. And I want the tooltip shown (hovered) to also be updated whenever I change the input field.
I am using bootstrap 4.3.1 tooltip.
What I initially did:

1. Make sure title attribute and data-toggle attributes are present on the input element.
2. Bind tooltip to input element itself.
3. Make an event listener for input event so that title is updated with the current input field value.

I encountered a couple of problems such as

1. Window custom tooltip also appearing and messing with display of the bootstrap tooltip.
2. Like yours, the displayed tooltip is always the same as the original one. I set the initial title attribute to some test string and it was always the one shown even if I edited the input. Note that I also confirmed that my code properly changes the title attribute on input event.

What I did after:

1. Wrap the input element with parent div. Add the data-toggle and title attributes here.
2. Bind tooltip to this parent.
3. On input listener callback function, I also added code to update the attribute "data-original-title". It seems to be the basis for whatever is displayed on the tooltip and I am not sure as to why it is not updated.

Initial code:
A. html

```
<input id="input_field" title="">
```

B. Javascript/Jquery

```
$('#input_field').attr({
    "data-toggle": "tooltip",
    "title": ""
});
$('#input_field').tooltip({
    placement: 'auto',
    trigger: 'hover',
    title: 'Fallback tooltip display'
});
$('#input_field').on('input', function(){
    $('#input_field').attr("title", $().val('#input_field'));
});
```

Code after:

A. html

```
<div>
    <input id="input_field" title="">
</div>
```

B. Javascript/Jquery

```
$('#input_field').parent().attr({
    "data-toggle": "tooltip",
    "title": ""
});
$('#input_field').parent().tooltip({
    placement: 'auto',
    trigger: 'hover',
    title: 'Fallback tooltip display'
});
$('#input_field').on('input', function(){
    $('#input_field').parent().attr("title", $('#input_field').val());
    $('#input_field').parent().attr("data-original-title", $('#input_field').val());
});
```